# Growing Hubble sphere

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

For the past few days I've been going through Baumann's notes on cosmology, more specifically I'm currently busy with chapter 2 Inflation. I don't get how he comes to the following equation involving a rewriting of the comoving Hubble radius
$$(aH)^{-1} = H_0^{-1}a^{\frac{1}{2}(1+3w)},$$
in which the $w$ comes from the equation of state $w = P/\rho$. Can anybody please help me with this?